# Webpack Encore - $ is not defined

Tags: symfony, webpack, twig, webpack-encore

I followed the documentation to make Webpack Encore work in my project.
Imported js files in webpack.config.js work fine but I have an issue in page-specific js : `$ is not defined`.

**Webpack.config.js** :

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var webpack = require('webpack');

Encore
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
.setPublicPath('http://localhost/tharmo/public/build')
.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
.autoProvidejQuery()

.createSharedEntry('vendor', [
    './assets/js/custom.js',
    'materialize-css',
])
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addEntry('statistiques', './assets/js/statistiques.js')
.addPlugin(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
}))

.enableSassLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**base.html.twig** :

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getNotifications(1);
    });
</script>
```

`$(document).ready` doesn't work.

Answer (score 39):

Got it working by following the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html).

I had to write this in app.js:

```
// require jQuery normally
const $ = require('jquery');

// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

And I removed this from webpack.conig.js since it's equivalent to `.autoProvidejQuery` :

```
.addPlugin(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
}))
```

Also make sure that the `defer` option is set to `false`:

```
# config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml
webpack_encore:
  script_attributes:
    defer: false
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh my god, THANK you for pointing me to the `defer: false`.  I spend an hour banging my head against the wall because some symfony recipe update set that to true, and I wasn't aware of what it did.  Man, thought I was going insane.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `output.library: "Root" //Or what name you want` config in webpack.config.js and in your entry js file do this:

> import $ from 'jquery'
>
> ... Your code of common entry file
>
> export {$};

And you will access jquery like this:

> Root.$

Comment: I tried both and I still have `$ is not defined` or `jquery is not defined`

Comment: Did you try `jQuery` instead of `jquery` ?