# Symfony 4 / Webpack Encore : jQuery doesn't work

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

jQuery doesn't work and I can't use my bootstrap dropdown, custom javascript...

After a `npm run dev` (or `npm run build`), `app.js` file is well created and loads in the browser.

Compilation is done without any error.

I tried to enable `.autoProvidejQuery()` then `npm run dev` / `npm run build`, but nothing changes.

I am using Symfony 4.1.6

**Solution found**

Change .enableSingleRuntimeChunk() to **.disableSingleRuntimeChunk()** in **webpack.config.js**

If you just comment on the line, it works but you have a warning message when you run a `npm run dev` or `npm run build`.

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
},
"dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('js/ad', './assets/js/ad.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')
    //.addStyleEntry('css/bootstrap', './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**app.js**

```
const $ = require('jquery');

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

require('bootstrap');
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SymBNB - {% block title %}Bienvenue !{% endblock %}</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/app.css') }}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-aOkxzJ5uQz7WBObEZcHvV5JvRW3TUc2rNPA7pe3AwnsUohiw1Vj2Rgx2KSOkF5+h" crossorigin="anonymous">

        {# <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"> #}
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'partials/header.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% include 'partials/footer.html.twig' %}

        {#<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>#}
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Similar topics:

[webpack symfony encore jquery third party plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359791/webpack-symfony-encore-jquery-third-party-plugins)

[Webpack Encore - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971680/webpack-encore-is-not-defined)

Comment: Is a simple console.log in your app.js showing a result ?

Comment: No but I found : it comes from .enableSingleRuntimeChunk() in webpack.config.js

Comment: did you try to change `.addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')` to `.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')` ?

Comment: The first message is edited with the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution found**

Change .enableSingleRuntimeChunk() to **.disableSingleRuntimeChunk()** in **webpack.config.js**

If you just comment on the line, it works but you have a warning message when you run a `npm run dev` or `npm run build`.

Comment: I followed the documentation thoroughly and did not have any issues with the jquery.

Comment: Your version of webpack-encore ?

Comment: Latest stable all.

Comment: Do you see any differences between my files and yours ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have `enableSingleRuntimeChunk()` in your `webpack.config.js` you need to add `<script src="{{ asset('build/runtime.js') }}"></script>` in your base template.

There is a Twig helper `encore_entry_script_tags()` to handle this automatically.

Comment: After hours of not knowing why my app was not working I found your answer and it worked. Thanks!!